# observable array using Proxy removes Array functionality

Tags: javascript, arrays, proxy

I'm trying to figure out how Proxy works.

So it seems the Array.observe() is being [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe) which is unfortunate for it's easy implementation. Anyways, after some research it seems the Proxy functionality was the way to go.

I managed to create an observable array (not sure if the way I created it, is well written however) whenever something is being pushed... BUT the Proxy seems to intercept every proto functionality. So I can't seem to get the length, nor can I simply retrieve a value using it's index, nothing...

For design reasons I can't have 2 arrays, so How do I manage to keep using Array functionalities but only observe it's push function?

```js
function observableArray (arr, callback) {
  console.log('create observableArray');
  return new Proxy(arr, {
    'get': function (target, prop) {
      console.log('prop', prop);
      if (prop === 'push') {
        return function (elem) {
          console.log('pushed element', elem);
          console.log('callback', callback);
          return Array.prototype[prop].apply(target, arguments);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

var list = [1, 2, 3];

list = observableArray(list, function () {
  console.log('test');
});

list.push(4);

console.log('list', list);

// Doesn't work, is being intercepted
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  console.log(list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it on my own after a break :)

You'd just need to return the prop used. Like so:

```
function createObservableArray (arr, callback) {
    console.log('create observableArray');
    return new Proxy(arr, {
        'get': function (target, prop) {
            console.log('prop', prop);
            if (prop === 'push') {
                return function (elem) {
                    console.log('pushed element', elem);
                    console.log('callback', callback);
                    return Array.prototype[prop].apply(target, arguments);
                }
            }
            return target[prop]; // <-
        }
    });
}
```